# The CDF of determinant of wishart distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-matrices

Assuming $b>0$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ with $m\leq n$ and each element of $\mathbf{A}$ is i.i.d. $\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ distributed, how to obtain $\mathbb{P} \left[ \det\left( \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^H \right) < b \right]$?

Comment: Here's a characterization of the distribution in terms of $\chi^2$: https://mathoverflow.net/a/268156/4600

Comment: It means that the determinant is distributed as the product of independent random variables with a chi-squared distribution, but I don't know that how to obtain the CDF of the product of independent random variables with a chi-squared distribution.

Comment: the [linked answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268156/4600) gives the asymptotics of the distribution for large $m$ and $n$; if $m$ and $n$ are small you can compute the CDF directly from the $\chi^2$ distributions; if $n,m$ are neither small nor large then there is no practical way to obtain a closed-form expression for the CDF.